# Desktop Environment with Workspace Management on multiple Monitors similar to i3

Tags: window-manager, i3, desktop-environment, workspaces

I currently use i3, but really think about switching to a full-fledged Desktop Environment (it's just more convenient).

I don't *really* need the tiling in i3, as I use it in tabbed-mode 90% of the time anyway.
What I really like about it though is how they handle Workspaces on multiple monitors.
I'll explain how it works down below, but my question essentially is: can I achieve the same behavior on any of the well-known DEs? As far as I can see, neither GNOME nor KDE have this as their default behavior and don't support it out-of-box. Are there any plugins/mods/other DEs where I get this behavior?

The behavior I mean:
Each workspace/virtual desktop (WS) is its own “unit” that can move between monitors (i.e., each WS is always assigned to a single monitor).
For example: I have my browser(s) open on WS1 and all chat related apps on WS2, my code editor is on WS3.
Most of the time I have WS1 and WS2 on my secondary monitor and WS3 on my main. If I have a longer chat, for example, I move WS2 to my main monitor, so I can sit straight while looking at it.
With i3 I can move the whole workspace using a key combination and don't have to move the single chat window.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.